# Google Direction API - Get travel time for all transportations

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am creating an application which provides the following modes of transportation: walking, driving, bus and bicycle.

Given start and destination coordinates, currently I can only query the travel time for a single transportation mode ( example: walking)

However, I would like to know the travel time for all transportation mode with one call. How can I do this?

I am using this library to connect with google direction API : http://www.akexorcist.com/2015/12/google-direction-library-for-android-en.html

```
public class OutdoorDirection implements DirectionCallback {

    public void requestDirection() {
         GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
            .from(origin)
            .to(destination)
            .transportMode(transportMode)
            .unit(Unit.METRIC)
            .execute(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to get this in a single request.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time